# Click function equlviant for dragging in Jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have my dragging set up by using jQuery UI. My question is when the user begins to drag a div, how do I add a CSS class to that div, and remove it when the user is done dragging the div. Similar to a click function event of a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$( ".selector" ).bind( "dragstart", function(event, ui) {
    $(this).addClass("foo");
});
$( ".selector" ).bind( "dragstop", function(event, ui) {
    $(this).removeClass("foo");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

"The jQuery UI Draggable plugin makes selected elements draggable by mouse.
Draggable elements gets a class of ui-draggable.
During drag the element also gets a class of ui-draggable-dragging"